# A novice question about mixed signal IC design

Tags: design, mixed-signal

As far as understand, a digital IC like a DSP can be design by RTL methods and by using languages like Verilog and VHDL.

And if I'm not wrong, we cannot yet program pure analog chips by using a language so SPICE simulators are used for design(?)

But for a mixed signal design of a chip, does that mean one expert desing the digital part(by using HDL) and the other expert analog part(by using SPICE)? So it takes two expert desing engineers for a mixed signal design? And they integrate it together in a way?

Comment: There's no reason it can't be the same engineer.

Comment: Thanks, I was mostly wondering is the analog IC  design part done only by SPICE software?

Comment: SPICE is only a simulation tool, not a design/layout tool. Other tools are required for that, and I'm not sure what the state of the art in that area currently is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

design is done in the human brain.

simulators are for verification

Comment: You are completly right, but given the confusion of the OT you might want to elaborate a little bit on what the difference is.